# How to use touch and drag and pinch to zoom in and out with aframe 0.9.0

Tags: aframe

I want to use touch and drag and pinch to zoom in and out with 0.9.0

The following code works with aframe 0.3.0 but isnt fully visible here, but
here [is link](https://jsfiddle.net/ks1505/mz6gp34q/3/) to the code

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>A-Frame Click & Drag Component - Basic</title>
        <script src="https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/build.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a-scene>

          <a-sphere look-controls click-drag position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
          <a-box click-drag position="-1 0.5 1" rotation="0 45 0" width="1" height="1" depth="1"  color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
          <a-cylinder click-drag position="1 0.75 1" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
          <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>

          <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>

          <a-entity position="0 0 3.8">
            <a-camera look-controls keyboard-controls="mode: fps"></a-camera>
          </a-entity>
        </a-scene>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So this is the 0.3.0 code but your looking for the 0.9.0 code? Have you tried writing something in 0.9.0 for the pinch to zoom/touch and drag? If so, can you add it here?

Comment: [This is the code](https://jsfiddle.net/ks1505/raty0bo3/) I tried adding wasd-controls of a-frame 0.9.0 for the object but its limited to Desktop since wasd controls cant be done from phones